# How to implement role based permission in React.Js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

I want to implement role-based permission in React. I have 3 different roles.

1. Operator
2. Supervisor
3. Admin

Each role has certain permissions.
Example: Operator can view user form but can not edit user. The supervisor can edit the form but can not delete the user. This is just an example. I have different 20-25 permissions. **(either canView / canEdit)**.

```
enum permission = {
   viewUser,
   editUser,
   viewReport,
   modifyReport,
   etc..
}
```

**Post Data: { permissionType: permission.viewUser }** // Backend will have already user role and id stored in service when user logged in, so no need to pass that.

**Response may look like: { canView: true, canEdit: false }**

**My Question:** Where and how can I create that enum and shared service (to make an API call at one place) so all the components can use that shared service to get the permissions and return results to component? I don't want to get all the permissions at once. As soon as I load the component, I want to make an API call and get specific permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate file for this (e.g permission.jsx) and import in any module needed

But I guess, this is not your question, more clarity will be better.

The other suggestion is to create an authorized component and wraps all the component that requires permission around it

Comment: My question is how and where can I create that enum and shared service (in which I want to put permission API call). So other component can import that service and use across the application.